# oninput event in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, events

Working with slider, I try to catch when the user is changing the value of the slider to display it, following this : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp

But this code is not working with typescript so for the moment I have the following code :

```
 var slider = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("myRange")).value;
    var output =  document.getElementById("demo");
    output.innerHTML = slider
```

To catch the event, I tried :

```
const onChange = output.innerHTML = slider;
```

But the value is not changing, do you know what is the event `oninput` in typescript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To catch changes you should use the method oninput of the slider object like this :

```
slider.oninput = e => {
    output.innerHTML = e.target.value;
};
```

Find a working pen as per w3s site example [here](https://codepen.io/shahatovic/pen/LYVEOXw)

Comment: just had to change `output.innerHTML = e.target.value;` by  `output.innerHTML = ((<HTMLTextAreaElement>e.target).value);` and it works thanks